# Web view на swift

Tags: swift, webview

На работе дали задание написать приложение на ios, в котором будет только web-view, которое будет открывать нужный сайт. Я использую x-code версии 8.0 язык swift. пишу следующий код

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var brouser: UIWebView!
let defaultURL = "https://yandex.ru"


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
            self.brouser.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: defaultURL)! as URL) as URLRequest)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}}
```

На эмуляторе появляется белое окно приложения и больше ничего не происходит. Подскажите пожалуйста как это исправить

Comment: Добавьте описание того, что должен, по Вашему мнению, делать этот код.

Comment: Я запустил приложение и оно открыло yandex.ru google.ru mail.ru habrahabr.ru, но нужный мне сайт не отрывает, как я понял он открывает только https версию сайта с мобильной версией, а другие игнорирует, не понимаю как это исправить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно в Info.plist разрешить загрузку через http.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Либо указать `Exception Domains`